# ASP.NET code will not run, getting error: The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got the following code, I wish to simply load the page in my browser running it with IIS 7.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%
using System;

protected string callRotate()
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    string[] arguments = { "arg1" , "arg2" };
    info.FileName = "ConsoleApplication1";

    Process process = Process.Start(info.FileName, arguments);
    Process.Start(info);
}
%>
```

Here is the error I get in the browser:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
Line 2:  <%
Line 3:  using System;
Line 4:  
Line 5:  protected string callRotate()

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\testing\testing.aspx    Line: 3
```

**Update 1:**
Now i'm getting this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1519: Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
Line 2:  <script runat="server">
Line 3:  using System;
Line 4:  
Line 5:  protected string callRotate()
```

**Update 2:**

Error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ProcessStartInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 5:  protected string callRotate()
Line 6:  {
Line 7:     ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Line 8:     string[] arguments = { "arg1" , "arg2" };
Line 9:     info.FileName = "ConsoleApplication1";

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\testing\testing.aspx    Line: 7
```

And here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<script runat="server">

protected string callRotate()
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    string[] arguments = { "arg1" , "arg2" };
    info.FileName = "ConsoleApplication1";

    Process process = Process.Start(info.FileName, arguments);
    Process.Start(info);
}
</script>
```

**Update 3:**
Ah okay, previously I switched to using a command line application as I couldn't get any of this code to work in the browser, but now you have shown me how I can switch back to running it in browser.

So I have taken my application and converted it to work in the browser and everything is fine. But how do I go about fetching url variables?

I know it's something to do with Request.QueryString but that won't work and I have added the following line:

Current code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

<script runat="server">
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = Request.QueryString["url"];
    string rotate_dir = Request.QueryString["dir"];

    //create an image object from the image in that path
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(url);

    //Rotate the image in memory
    if (direction == "clockwise")
    {
        //Rotate clockwise
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    } else if (direction == "anticlockwise") 
    {
        //Rotate anti-clockwise
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
    }

    //Delete the file so the new image can be saved
    System.IO.File.Delete(url);

    //save the image to the file
    img.Save(url);

    //release image file
    img.Dispose();
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the folder structure of your site?

Comment: Did you check whether `tesing.aspx` is spelled correctly?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a separate code behind file?  It would likely make more sense to have a C# code file that does with the page rather than put everything in the mark-up.

Comment: This is a really confusing question since your updates say your new results without actually seemingly saying what the changes are that cause these new errors...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you did not show the actual page name in your posted code, I am going to assume that `tesing.aspx` is supposed to be `testing.aspx`, change your URL to this:

```
/testing/testing.aspx
```

UPDATE 1:

You are trying to use in-line embedded code blocks via the `<%` syntax, but you need to use the `<script` syntax because your logic is spanning more than a single line.

Try this instead:

```
<script runat="server">
    using System; 

    protected string callRotate()
    ... Rest of your code here
</script>
```

UPDATE 2:

Embedded code blocks do not allow for the use of the C# `using` statement, instead you have to use the `@ Import` page directive, like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
```

UPDATE 3:

The `ProcessStartInfo` class is part of the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, so add the following import for that, like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
```

UPDATE 4:

You can combine your file name and arguments together, like this:

```
Process execute = new Process();
execute.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleApplication1";
execute.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-log d:file.txt -c ""arg2"" -y ""arg3"" -z ""HOW?""";
execute.Start()
```

Note: The `Arguments` value here is made up, because I am not sure what flags you have setup in your console application named `ConsoleApplication1`.

UPDATE 5:

Change the method in your `script` block to handle the ASP.NET Page_Load event, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = Request.QueryString["url"];
    string rotate_dir = Request.QueryString["dir"];
}
```

Comment: Error with "using System;" as you can see in my updated post.

Comment: You cannot use `using` statements in embedded code blocks, you have to use the `@ Import` page directive, see updated answer. Sorry, it has been a while since I have used embedded code blocks, so I apologize for missing that point earlier.

Comment: The file just so you know is saved as followed
`http://localhost/testing/testing.aspx`

I now get this error:
`Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Import' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: See UPDATE 3 in my answer.

Comment: It seems there is only one more issue.
`Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string, string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: You cannot pass a string array (`string[]`) to as a parameter to `Process.Start()`, it is expecting two parameters; each being a string. See UPDATE4 in my answer.

Comment: So this is a web application, so why is the method `Main()` instead of `Page_Load`?

Comment: It is now, wasn't before as I couldn't get it working, I don't understand how to get it working in the background, so basically load it using ajax and return the result.

Comment: Well the `Request` is going to be of little use if you run this from the command-line.

Comment: I wan't to run it from the web browser now instead, how would I make it work in browser?

Comment: See UPDATE 5 for using `Page_Load` event instead of `Main()`.